# Oracle compare string

Tags: string, oracle, compare, equals, sql-like

I have a strange issue in Oracle I never seen before....

I have the following insert select statement

```
insert into table2
(
    key_field,value
)
SELECT 
       key_field, CASE WHEN type ='S' THEN 100 ELSE 1 END 
FROM view1
WHERE key_field=1
```

When I run just the SELECT part then I get 100 for the second field, 
however if I run the insert select statement the I get 1 in table2 .

If I include the field type on the insert, the I get the 100

If I use "CASE WHEN type **like** 'S' THEN 100 ELSE 1 END" Then I get 100 in table2 (correct answer)

Anyone has any idea why the first select insert statement is not working?

Thank you!

Comment: where is type being populated? it looks like you're inserting into the same table and if type isn't declared then it becomes null which is not 'S' so you get 1

Comment: Please post `table2` definition. What is a type of `type` field? Look like `type` is fixed width char field

Comment: Hi, there was an error on the query, I´ve corrected it changing table2 (on the select part) to view1. The view does not have any relation with table2.